# Mongoose get all documents matching array intersection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

By array intersection I mean, the inventory has a lot more elements than each document ingredients array, and the result I want to get from the query is all documents which all array elements are contained within the inventory. $all will get me zero results since the inventory has more elements than can be found in ingredients even if all ingredients are found within the inventory,

I have thousands of docs that have an array field of strings

```
{
 ...
  recipe: "recipe1",
  ingredients: [ "1 cup cooked quinoa", "6 tbsp butter", "1 large egg" ]
 ...
},
{
 ...
  recipe: "recipe2",
  ingredients: [ "2 lemons", "2 tbsp butter", "1 large egg" ]
 ...
}
{
 ...
  recipe: "recipe3",
  ingredients: [ "1lb salmon", "1 pinch pepper", "4 spears asparagus" ]
 ...
}
```

and I'm trying to find all documents where all elements in the `ingredients` array are contained in a sample array that contains lots of elements, lets say for the case this only contains this:

```
inventory = [ "lemons", "butter", "egg", "milk", "bread", "salmon", "asparagus", "pepper" ]
```

With this inventory array, I want to get recipe2 and recipe3.
Right now I have this inventory array and query (thanks to [turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal)):

```
    let inventory = ["lemons", "butter", "egg", "milk", "bread", "salmon", "asparagus", "pepper"];
inventory = inventory.map((i) => new RegExp(i, "i"));
```

query:

```
    Recipe.find({
  ingredients: { $all: inventory }
})
```

Expected result:

```
{
 ...
  recipe: "recipe2",
  ingredients: [ "2 lemons", "2 tbsp butter", "1 large egg" ]
 ...
}
{
 ...
  recipe: "recipe3",
  ingredients: [ "1lb salmon", "1 pinch pepper", "4 spears asparagus" ]
 ...
}
```

But I'm getting zero results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregation operator in mquery using `$expr` expression condition,

- first of all you can join the array of string by `|` order symbol and make a string, and use it in `$regex` search,
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `ingredients`
- `$regexMatch` to match element has any matching word
- `$size` to get the total size of filtered elements
- `$eq` to match filtered result and actual `ingredients` is equal

```
let inventory = ["lemons", "butter", "egg", "milk", "bread", "salmon", "asparagus", "pepper"];
let inventoryStr = inventory.join("|");
// "lemons|butter|egg|milk|bread|salmon|asparagus|pepper"

Recipe.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$ingredients",
            cond: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$$this",
                regex: inventoryStr,
                options: "i"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { $size: "$ingredients" }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxBo7dfrF4Q)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the array iteration problem, but this would give me all three recipes since inventory contains butter and all recipes contain butter. So what I need is to get only the documents that passes the intersection of inventory with their own ingredients field. Having said that I think I need to change the question title to find array intersection

Comment: i have updated question with `$all` option, I am not sure, can you explain how you mean by array intersection?

Comment: not sure how the map should work with the new RegExp, im getting something like this from the map: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: it will return regular expression string, see i have added snippet you can run and see console result.

Comment: By array intersection i mean, the inventory has a lot more elements than each document ingredient, and the result i want to get from the query is all documents which all array elements are contained within the inventory. $all is not working because of the inventory map output, but i think $all will get me zero results since the inventory has more elements than can be found in ingredients

Comment: Yes, sorry, the RegExp map was good, just that I forgot to use .lean() to get the inventory from inventory model and it was a mongoose array object instead of a javascript array

Comment: okay no problem, you have resolved your query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233035/discussion-between-jarki-and-turivishal).